# manipulate strings in C

Tags: c, string, character, ascii, digit

I have to save how many letters, numbers, whitespaces and lines there are in a string:

```
char string[2048];
...
string = "aaa 111\nsas 23 d\nds";
for(i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++){
    if (isdigit(string[i]) != 0){
        numbers++;
    } else if (isascii(string[i]) != 0){
        letters++;
    } ...
}
```

It gaves me many error, "incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[2048]’ from type ‘char *’" and other errors

What's wrong in that code?

thank you,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char string[2048] = "aaa 111\nsas 23 d\nds";
n = strlen(string);
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (isdigit(string[i]) != 0){
        numbers++;
    } else if (isascii(string[i]) != 0){
        letters++;
    } ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
char string[2048];

strcpy(string,"aaa 111\nsas 23 d\nds");
```

or

```
char string[2048] = "aaa 111\nsas 23 d\nds";
```

Instead of

```
char string[2048];

string = "aaa 111\nsas 23 d\nds";
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I get that string by a read(socket..) from a client..  that code is in the server, the string arrives through a socket, so it's like this:

read(client_socket, string, 2048);

Comment: Then there is no need to copy the string ? Just using string directly ?

Comment: @lore_barba if string is read from client socket then it can be copied using `strcpy`. Refer http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node19.html for basics on C & strings

Comment: yeah you're right, maybe I have to do strcpy.. I haven't tried yet but I think it's the right solution

Answer (score 1):

### Short version

You declared string as an array of size 2048 of char:

```
char string[2048];
```

This line is causing troubles because you assign a char* which is a pointer:

```
string = "aaa 111\nsas 23 d\nds";
```

Try the following command which will iterate over the char* and copy the element until reaching the end of the string:

```
strcpy(string, "aaa 111\nsas 23 d\nds");
```

If you just want to give an initial value to this char[], use:

```
char string[2048] = "aaa 111\nsas 23 d\nds";
```

### Long version

What you do is kind of ok in this case but in practice, it can be dangerous to use fixed size arrays of chars. If you were to try to copy a string over 2048 chars you would be writing after the space allocated for this variable.

The reason you cannot just assign is that they are array of chars, it is not an operation really defined in C, the char[2048] is only kind of a pointer on a space of length `2048*sizeof(char)`. `strcpy()` will iterate on the second argument and copy the characters until finding `0` which will mark the end of your string.

You may want to check `strncpy()` as it is safer in the case you have a string larger than the buffer. From the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strncpy/):

> The stpncpy() and strncpy() functions copy at most n characters from
>   s2 into s1.  If s2 is less than n characters long, the remainder of s1
>   is filled with `\0' characters.  Otherwise, s1 is not terminated.

Comment: Glad it was useful, by the way,even if you were not using a `char[]` but a `char*`, if you were to write `string1 = string2`, you would not copy the string but just change the pointer value to point to the same memory space.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcpy` instead of assigning like `string = "aaa 111\nsas 23 d\nds";` or initialize string array as `char string[2048] = "aaa 111\nsas 23 d\nds";`.